# How to use drag and drop arguments with a short cut in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a C# Winforms application where I want to drag and drop files onto the icon and have the application launch and open the files.

I have added the code into the application and have everything working so that I can drag and drop files onto the exe and the application launches and opens the files properly.

The problem I have is that today my installer creates a directory (that the user can change at install time) to install the exe in along with all of the supporting files and then places a short cut to the exe on the desktop. I can't see how I can get the shortcut to take the drag and drop arguments and pass them to the exe. I also thought about dropping the exe on the desktop but then I am not clear how I could grab the actual installed path of the rest of the files at install time or run time to point the exe to the required directory.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: *how I can get the shortcut to take the drag and drop arguments and pass them to the exe*: the System already does that. The path(s) of the file(s) dropped onto the shortcut are passed to the application. Read what the `args[]` array you receive in `main` (`Program.cs`) contains. -- Note that command-line switches (if any) come before the paths of the files.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change `static void Main()` in `static void Main(string args[])`?

Comment: I have everything handled in static void Main() and it works fine if I drop the files directly on the exe. However Windows does not even let me drop the files on the shortcut. Maybe I have a Windows settings problem?

Comment: So, if you drag some files from Explorer onto the shortcut the Installer created on the Desktop, you don't see the `➕ Open with [your app name]` tooltip appear?

Comment: No I get a red circle with a line through it.

Comment: Then you probably have an [Advertisement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/advertisement) instead of a standard shortcut. Add to the question all relevant details related to the Installer you're using and its configuration.